# How to get value based on key from an array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an array which I get from Database as below

```
var sampleArray = 
{ID:1, ANALYSIS_NAME : "name1",
   custodians:"[{\"ID\": 1, \"NAME\": \"abc\"}, 
                {\"ID\": 2, \"NAME\": \"xyz\"}, 
                {\"ID\": 3, \"NAME\": \"pqr\"}]"

};
```

How do I get name from the above array. I am able to display `console.log(sampleArray.custodians)` But When I tried to display `console.log(sampleArray.custodians.name)` I am getting an error `Cannot read property 'NAME' of undefined`.

```
return(<div>
<Panel>test</panel>
/*custodians should come here*/
</div>)
```

How to display the above object? please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: The value of `custodians` is JSON, so you first have to parse it -> `JSON.parse()`

Comment: `sampleArray` is not an array it's an object. Also, `custodians` is stringified (serialized as text).

Answer (score 2):

Part of the issue is because `sampleArray.custodians` is a JSON formatted string. You will need to deserialise it before you access it.

The other part of the issue is that the result of the deserialisation will convert `custodians` to an array, so you will need to access it directly by index or through a loop.

```js
var sampleArray = {
  ID: 1,
  ANALYSIS_NAME: "name1",
  custodians: "[{\"ID\": 1, \"NAME\": \"abc\"},{\"ID\": 2, \"NAME\": \"xyz\"},{\"ID\": 3, \"NAME\": \"pqr\"}]"
};

let custodians = JSON.parse(sampleArray.custodians);

custodians.forEach(c => console.log('loop', c.NAME)); // loop

console.log('index', custodians[0].NAME); // direct access by index
```

*-- UPDATE --*

Given the update to your question, you can use `map()` to build the HTML string to return from your function:

```js
var sampleArray = {
  ID: 1,
  ANALYSIS_NAME: "name1",
  custodians: "[{\"ID\": 1, \"NAME\": \"abc\"},{\"ID\": 2, \"NAME\": \"xyz\"},{\"ID\": 3, \"NAME\": \"pqr\"}]"
};


let buildCustodianHtml = (data) => {
  let custodianHtml = JSON.parse(data.custodians).map(c => `<p>${c.NAME}</p>`).join('');
  return `<div><Panel>test</panel>${custodianHtml}</div>`;
}

$('#container').append(buildCustodianHtml(sampleArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I have edited my question. How do I display in the code where I added the comment /*custodians should come here*/

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to do that

Answer (score 0):

The custodians property is a string. You first need to convert this string into JSON using

`var custodians = JSON.parse(sampleArray.custodians);`

Then you can access it using

`console.log(custodians[0].NAME)`

Comment: I have edited my question. How do I display in the code where I added the comment /*custodians should come here*/

Answer (score 0):

Since **custodians** is a string, it needs to converted to an object first before "NAME" can be accessed.

Use JavaScript's built-in **JSON.Parse()**

```js
var sampleArray = 
    {
    ID:1, ANALYSIS_NAME : "name1",
    custodians:`[{\"ID\": 1, \"NAME\": \"abc\"}, 
                {\"ID\": 2, \"NAME\": \"xyz\"}, 
                {\"ID\": 3, \"NAME\": \"pqr\"}]`

};

let newObj = JSON.parse(sampleArray.custodians);

for(let i=0; i<newObj.length; i++){
    console.log(`Name: ${newObj[i]["NAME"]}`);
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. How do I display in the code where I added the comment /*custodians should come here*/